# How can i set the binding protocol to be https when creating a website in IIS using c#?

Tags: c#, iis

I am using the following:

```
  Site website = iisManager.Sites.Add(name.ToString(), location,port);
  website.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName = appPoolName;
  website.ServerAutoStart = true;                    
  iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

If i use this it sets the binding as http, how can i force it to be https ?

I am also trying set up the SSL settings:

```
var site = iisManager.Sites.First(s => s.Name == name);
Configuration config =   
       iisManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();                    
ConfigurationSection accessSection = 
config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/access", site.Name);
accessSection["sslFlags"] = "Ssl,SslRequireCert";
iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

but the value is not saved , any ideas ?

Comment: You can add Binding to site.Bindings property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.bindingcollection.add?view=iis-dotnet

Comment: that worked thanks. I am also trying to set the SSL flags , but doesnt seem to be working. I have updated the question.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/access

Comment: the GetApplicationHostConfiguration doesnt bring back the file. does the web.config need to be in a specific location,  or do i need to pass through the path location ?

Comment: Did you try setting only one value `Ssl` instead of two values for `sslFlags` ?

Comment: instead of GetApplicationHostConfiguration I used GetWebConfiguration

Comment: This link may help you: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding#c](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding#c).